# Element undefined after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading content in center div via ajax. When the page loads for first time, I am showing rows coming from database. Each row is shown in DIV and the id of each DIV is dynamically created like `<div id="div_[record's ID]">`

I have included javascript function that changes the color of that div on onClick event on that div. Everything is working fine so far.

I am loading records after ajax call on that center div if user clicks on category on left navigation. The ids of newly created divs are created dynamically same as ids were created when page loaded for the first time but now when user clicks on that div, element is undefined.

Ajax is asynchronous but i am not touching that javascript function at all, it must read elements that were created on page load and also elements after ajax call.

Here is code of Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
url: window.base_url+'back/home/contentAjax/'+listing_status+'/'+type_id+'/',
data: { listing_status : listing_status, type_id : type_id },
dataType: 'text',
type: 'post',
success: function (j) {
$('.center').html(j);
}
});
```

This div is created dynamically :

```
<form id=frmNode name=frmNode>

<div id="div_<?php echo $counter; ?>">  
<input  type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $listing_row->nid; ?>" id="nid" name="nid[]" onclick="markSelectedNode(<?php echo $counter; ?>);" />

</form>
```

Only that div gets populated after ajax call. The form tag remain unchanged.

And this is javascript code that reads that element :

alert(document.frmNode.nid[selectedId]);

Actually I am getting that div element but input is undefine.

Comment: Show the code for the ajax call and the code where the element is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I got where i was wrong. Actually the form tag was not properly created inside div. It was started inside main div and closed after main div.
This is why javascript was not able to recognize 
document.frmNode.nid[selectedId]